# Disable/enable field based on other field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, dropdown

I want to disable/enable the Dropdown field based on the selected other Dropdown field in SharePoint list.

Disable field"B" until User select the dropdown of Field"A"

Comment: Please give clarity to the question, which is high level

Comment: Hey Suresh, Which one do you want to clarify? I guess its simple to understand. I have two field(A and B) both are drop down. I need to disable field B until user selected dropdown from field A.

Comment: do you want it in JSOM or CSOM or SPServices in default share Point list new/edit forms ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to SharePoint Designer you should be able to do this using conditional formatting.

[Check This Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-Data-Views-and-forms-using-SharePoint-Designer-4201233c-ce24-42c2-9f2a-31f202c440cc?CorrelationId=f86c8e30-6682-471a-bc08-29ce9ac65772&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA101631678)

Answer (score 1):

You can use InfoPath to customize the list form, then use a rule to disable the drop-down list when the selection of another dropdown list is not A.

The rue is like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use SharePoint Client Side Rendering (CSR) concept to disable the fields in the list view. Find some examples [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a). Find other links for [CSR](http://www.kaptyn.com/SharePoint/client-side-rendering-2013/)